# Kendo UI for JQuery with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, kendo-ui

I use KendoUI for JQuery along with TypeScript. My "package.json" is:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-theme-material": "^3.19.2",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2020.3.915",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/kendo-ui": "^2020.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
  }
```

#### 1) My "script.ts" file looks like this and I get these errors:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/kendo-ui/index.d.ts" />  

import '@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.tabstrip';
import '@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.treeview';
import '@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.multiselect';
import '@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.dropdowntree';
import '@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.button';
import '@Progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.scss';
    
$("#my-1").kendoMultiSelect({
  <...>,
  messages: {
    clear: "Clear!"
  }
});
    
$("#my-2").kendoDropDownTree({
  <...>,
  select: function (e) {            
    if (e.sender.dataItem(e.node).type !== 2) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
});
    
// let dataSource: kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource;
dataSource.transport.options = {
  read: {
    url: '<url>',
    dataType: "json"
  }
};
```

Errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./script.ts:121:9 
    TS2345: Argument of type '{ dataSource: DataSource; dataTextField: string; dataValueField: string; filter: string; autoClose: true; change: (e: MultiSelectChangeEvent) => void; tagTemplate: (data: any) => string; tagMode: string; messages: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MultiSelectOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'messages' does not exist in type 'MultiSelectOptions'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./script.ts:228:26 
    TS2339: Property 'dataItem' does not exist on type 'DropDownTree'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./script.ts:381:20 
    TS2339: Property 'transport' does not exist on type 'HierarchicalDataSource'.
```

This error occurs in the browser console when you start it:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: kendo.observable is not a function**

#### 2) If you add import for observable:

```
import '@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.binder';
```

everything starts working, there are no errors in the browser. But the errors still remained and more warnings were added:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.core.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.core.js
    Used by 9 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.button.js
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.core.js
    Used by 4 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.binder.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.core.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.button.js
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/mapFilter.ts
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
 @ multi ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
WARNING in ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.js
    Used by 5 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.tabstrip.js
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.binder.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.tabstrip.js
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/mapFilter.ts
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
 @ multi ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
WARNING in ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.odata.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.odata.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.js
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.odata.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.odata.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.tabstrip.js
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/mapFilter.ts
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
 @ multi ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
WARNING in ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.xml.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.xml.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@Progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.js
* C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.xml.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\<project>\node_modules\@progress\kendo-ui\js\kendo.data.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.xml.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.data.js
 @ ./node_modules/@Progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.tabstrip.js
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/mapFilter.ts
 @ ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
 @ multi ./<sub_project>/Areas/Map/JScripts/map.ts
```

#### 3. If I replace all import Kendo with one like this:

```
import "@progress/kendo-ui";
```

But the errors still remained and added more of these (however, everything works in the browser):

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:16:1 
    TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: Class, Observable, View, ViewContainer, Layout, History, Route, Router, Binding, BindingTarget, EventBinding, TemplateBinding, Binder, TypedBinder, ObservableObject, Model, SchedulerEvent, TreeListModel, TreeListDataSource, GanttTask, GanttDependency, Node, FileEntry, SchedulerDataSource, GanttDataSource, GanttDependencyDataSource, HierarchicalDataSource, FileManagerDataSource, PivotDataSource, ObservableArray, DataSource, Query, attr, css, style, enabled, disabled, readonly, events, text, visible, invisible, html, value, source, checked, start, end, Widget, Draggable, DropTarget, DropTargetArea, Toolbar, Alert, AppBar, AutoComplete, Button, ButtonGroup, Calendar, Chat, ColorPalette, ColorPicker, ComboBox, Confirm, ContextMenu, DateInput, DatePicker, DateRangePicker, DateTimePicker, Dialog, Drawer, DropDownList, DropDownTree, Editor, FileManager, Filter, FilterMenu, FlatColorPicker, Form, Gantt, Grid, ImageEditor, ListBox, ListView, Loader, MaskedTextBox, MediaPlayer, Menu, MultiColumnComboBox, MultiSelect, MultiViewCalendar, Notification, NumericTextBox, PDFViewer, Pager, PanelBar, PivotConfigurator, PivotGrid, Popup, ProgressBar, Prompt, RangeSlider, Rating, ResponsivePanel, Scheduler, ScrollView, Slider, Sortable, Splitter, Spreadsheet, Switch, Stepper, TabStrip, TileLayout, TextArea, TextBox, TimePicker, Timeline, ToolBar, Tooltip, Touch, TreeList, TreeView, Upload, Validator, Window, Wizard, Application, ActionSheet, Badge, BackButton, Collapsible, DetailButton, ModalView, NavBar, Pane, PopOver, Scroller, SplitView, ArcGauge, Barcode, Chart, Diagram, LinearGauge, Map, QRCode, RadialGauge, Sparkline, StockChart, TreeMap, Shape, BingLayer, Extent, Layer, Location, Marker, MarkerLayer, ShapeLayer, TileLayer, ChartAxis, ChartPane, ChartPlotArea, ChartPoint, ChartSeries, Navigator, Circle, Connection, Connector, Group, Image, Line, Path, Point, Polyline, Rect, Rectangle, TextBlock, Arc, Element, Gradient, GradientStop, LinearGradient, MultiPath, OptionsStore, RadialGradient, Segment, Surface, Text, Matrix, Size, Transformation, Color, CustomFilter, DynamicFilter, Range, Sheet, TopFilter, ValueFilter, Step, Workbook
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:15:1 
    TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: Class, Observable, View, ViewContainer, Layout, History, Route, Router, Binding, BindingTarget, EventBinding, TemplateBinding, Binder, TypedBinder, ObservableObject, Model, SchedulerEvent, TreeListModel, TreeListDataSource, GanttTask, GanttDependency, Node, FileEntry, SchedulerDataSource, GanttDataSource, GanttDependencyDataSource, HierarchicalDataSource, FileManagerDataSource, PivotDataSource, ObservableArray, DataSource, Query, attr, css, style, enabled, disabled, readonly, events, text, visible, invisible, html, value, source, checked, start, end, Widget, Draggable, DropTarget, DropTargetArea, Toolbar, Alert, AppBar, AutoComplete, Button, ButtonGroup, Calendar, Chat, ColorPalette, ColorPicker, ComboBox, Confirm, ContextMenu, DateInput, DatePicker, DateRangePicker, DateTimePicker, Dialog, Drawer, DropDownList, DropDownTree, Editor, FileManager, Filter, FilterMenu, FlatColorPicker, Form, Gantt, Grid, ImageEditor, ListBox, ListView, Loader, MaskedTextBox, MediaPlayer, Menu, MultiColumnComboBox, MultiSelect, MultiViewCalendar, Notification, NumericTextBox, PDFViewer, Pager, PanelBar, PivotConfigurator, PivotGrid, Popup, ProgressBar, Prompt, RangeSlider, Rating, ResponsivePanel, Scheduler, ScrollView, Slider, Sortable, Splitter, Spreadsheet, Switch, Stepper, TabStrip, TileLayout, TextArea, TextBox, TimePicker, Timeline, ToolBar, Tooltip, Touch, TreeList, TreeView, Upload, Validator, Window, Wizard, Application, ActionSheet, Badge, BackButton, Collapsible, DetailButton, ModalView, NavBar, Pane, PopOver, Scroller, SplitView, ArcGauge, Barcode, Chart, Diagram, LinearGauge, Map, QRCode, RadialGauge, Sparkline, StockChart, TreeMap, Shape, BingLayer, Extent, Layer, Location, Marker, MarkerLayer, ShapeLayer, TileLayer, ChartAxis, ChartPane, ChartPlotArea, ChartPoint, ChartSeries, Navigator, Circle, Connection, Connector, Group, Image, Line, Path, Point, Polyline, Rect, Rectangle, TextBlock, Arc, Element, Gradient, GradientStop, LinearGradient, MultiPath, OptionsStore, RadialGradient, Segment, Surface, Text, Matrix, Size, Transformation, Color, CustomFilter, DynamicFilter, Range, Sheet, TopFilter, ValueFilter, Step, Workbook
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:557:9 
    TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:1044:9 
    TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:1056:9 
    TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:1076:9 
    TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts:4320:9 
    TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
```

How can I use Kendo UI for JQuery with TypeScript without errors and warnings?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the docs: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/typescript

Notice they refer to `kendo.all.d.ts`, not `index`.

Keep in mind the typings are far from perfect, as you can see here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues?q=is%3Aissue+typings

You may need to cast to `<any>` or extend the typings in some cases.

Comment: If you do npm, the file "kendo.all.d.ts" is missing in node_modules, there is "index.d.ts". But it is completely equivalent to the file "typescript\kendo.all.d.ts" from the archive "<...>commercial.zip".